# How to read / list security labels on columns in postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I've set up [PostgreSQL Anonymizer](https://postgresql-anonymizer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) on my database with security labels and everything works fine.

I'm trying to regularly ceck if there is missing security labels on the columns of my database to telle the developers to add them in the next release but I can't fin a way to read the security labels.

Can anyone know how to do this ?

#### EDIT on 10/11/2022

Thanks to @Shiva, I've end up doing this query :

```
select cl."oid", col.ordinal_position, col.table_schema, col.table_name, col.column_name
FROM information_schema.columns col
join pg_catalog.pg_class cl on cl.relname = col.table_name
WHERE col.table_schema = 'XXXX'
and not exists (select objoid FROM pg_seclabel where provider = 'anon' and objsubid = col.ordinal_position and objoid = cl."oid");
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to query [`pg_seclabel`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-seclabel.html) catalog to get list of security labels.

```sql
SELECT objsubid, provider, label FROM pg_seclabel WHERE objoid::regclass = 'mytable'::regclass
```

`objsubid` is the column number whose corresponding column name can be found by querying `information_schema.columns` catalog.

```sql
SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = 'mytable' AND ordinal_position = <column_number>
```

You can combine the above two queries to find columns that do not have the required security labels.

Comment: Thanks ! I need to get the classoid of the tables too, as ordinal_position is not unique

Answer (score 0):

I have nothing to add to the answers above to the specific question posted...but for anyone else coming here and looking only at the subject line

> How to read / list security labels on columns in postgreSQL

a more convenient, possibly workable solution may be in looking only at `pg_seclabel`, without the join, e.g.:

```
select objtype,objname,label from pg_seclabels 
 where objtype in ('table','column') 
   and objname LIKE '%mytablename%';
```